# Error when calling when calling `increaseLiquidity ` in nonFungiblePositionManager

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I have failing tests when calling `increaseLiquidity`  in nonFungiblePositionManager. `decreaseLiquidity` works as expected but increaseLiquidity is failing.

This is the code:

```
 underlyingPositionManager.increaseLiquidity(
            INonfungiblePositionManager.IncreaseLiquidityParams({
                tokenId: loan.tokenId,
                amount0Desired: amount0,
                amount1Desired: amount1,
                amount0Min: 0,
                amount1Min: 0,
                deadline: block.timestamp
            })
```

This is the foundry output for the test

```
[12350] 0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88::increaseLiquidity((512098 [5.12e5], 0, 671529 [6.715e5], 0, 0, 1685033235 [1.685e9])) 
    │   │   ├─ [696] 0xCBCdF9626bC03E24f779434178A73a0B4bad62eD::slot0() [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 0x000000000000000000000000000000000005db000f1598ba8f0e02e024506208000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ec8f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    │   │   ├─ [3747] 0xCBCdF9626bC03E24f779434178A73a0B4bad62eD::mint(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88, 253320, 264600, 0, 0x0000000000000000000000002260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000002e234dae75c793f67a35089c9d99245e1c58470b) 
    │   │   │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    │   │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    │   └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
    └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"

Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 424.01ms
 
Ran 1 test suites: 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)
```

Can someone tell me what might be the issue, thank you.

Comment: Check approvals, always check approvals first even if you think they're correct.

Comment: Approvals seem to work fine, and the decreaseLiquidity is working as well

Comment: From the Uniswap source code, mint reverts without a reason string when the `liquidity` amount is zero. You're likely passing the wrong amounts.